# Android If Host 404 show Toast

Tags: android, http-status-code-404

There is no data becouse my server down, I want show toast Massage "server down try again" But i always have default adnroid 404 massage like (Error:404 error loading url somesite.com), But i need my own toast for show, don't want show my host name. i use try cath

My button for search:

```
  button_search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
                      Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(search_input.getWindowToken(), 0);
                msgLoading.show();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {


            new Thread(new Runnable() { 
                public void run() { 
                 try {
                     list_songs = wrzuta_class.search(search_input.getText().toString());
                    } catch (Throwable e) {
                    show_error("Error: "+e.getMessage());
                    }

                refresh_list();

                            } 
                    }).start(); 

                    }
            });
        }
    });
```

My refresh_list:

```
 public void refresh_list(){
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
    List<Map<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
     try {
        for (song_details song_item_loop : list_songs) {
            Map<String, String> datum = new HashMap<String, String>(2);
            datum.put("title", song_item_loop.title);
            datum.put("url", song_item_loop.url);
            datum.put("description", song_item_loop.size);
            data.add(datum);    
        }
     } catch (NullPointerException ex) { 
         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, 
                    "server down try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

i Also tried:

```
  public void refresh_list(){
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
    List<Map<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    if (list_songs == null || list_songs.size() == 0) {
         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, 
                        "server down try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {

         for (song_details song_item_loop : list_songs) {
                Map<String, String> datum = new HashMap<String, String>(2);
                datum.put("title", song_item_loop.title);
                datum.put("url", song_item_loop.url);
                datum.put("description", song_item_loop.size);
                data.add(datum);    
            }
     }
```

Still I have (Error:404 error loading url somesite.com)...  how can replace this error

FIXED:

I added:

```
    public void show_error(final String valString){
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, 
                        "server down try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
        });
}
```

Comment: do you have a toast in your show_error("Error: "+e.getMessage()); method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the for loop does not throw an exception so it does not go to your catch phrase. I would suggest that you check for nullity before the for loop and and show the toast message there.

```
if (list_songs == null || list_songs.size() == 0) {
     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, 
                    "server down try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 return;
}
```

It seems that you show the toast in show_error() method.

Comment: Still I have "Error:404 error loading url somesite.com"

Comment: So you have toast with this message? Are you sure that your code even calls this method?

Comment: Can you run your app in debug mode and place a break point in the beginning of the method and see if it actually goes there. I suspect your method was ever called.

Comment: When my domain is working its all working fine.. if my domain down i have this error Error:404 error loading url somesite.com.. I dont want show 404 error with my domain name